# execute script before OnDisconnected method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to execute js script before a connection is closed, for example when I closed the web-page or refresh it.
I have OnDisconnected method on the server-side, and it works well, but I can`t use local storage, so and need to execute a script 
on the client-side (In my case save the date when the user is disconnected, to local storage)

Something like this:

```
connection.disconnected(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("disconnDate", date);
});
```

UPDATE.
Solved this problem this way:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("disconnDate", date);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onclose` method of Client-Side connection:

```js
connection.onclose(() => {
    var date = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem("disconnDate", date);
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to work this code on leaving page. You can add such event listener

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
   connection.stop();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when closing the browser or reloading the page.

Comment: I see that you have solved it a similar  way. Anyway, I recommend you to use `onclose` method because in this way you can also log when the internet connection or server is down.